# How to do RegAsm so that it cover 32-bit and 64-bit?

Tags: c#, windows, com, regasm, regedit

I have a DLL file prepared by C# and my system is Windows 7 64-bit. 
When i apply the RegAsm its not adding the registry to 64-bit path but only adding it to 32-bit path.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /register /codebase "C:\o.dll"
```

then if i check my GUID in regedit.exe i see that i have it only in 32-bit registry path: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{... my guid is found here ....}`

instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{... not found my guid ...}`

As a result i have other issues for this. Can anyone please suggest what is going on and why its not making 32-bit and 64-bit registry entries?"

Comment: Is the parameter `/register` still valid? I found nothing here in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have it backwards. The Wow6432Node is where the 32-bit specific data goes. Use the 32-bit regasm (from the Framework directory, not the Framework64 directory) to have your component registered in the Wow6432Node.

Answer (score 15):

also, you probably compiled your dll with AllCPU option
try to compile with x64 and/or x86 option and register like you do

- for x64 - `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /register /codebase "C:\x64\o.dll"`
- for x86 - `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /register /codebase "C:\x86\o.dll"`

P.S. its 5yo question, but may be help to other peoples

Answer (score -1):

On my 2016 windows server it was the opposite, it was an old dll that needed to be registered using the "Framework" folder, not the "Framework64" folder:
"C:\windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm" /register /codebase "full path to dll here"