# Not able to create SQL server SMO automation object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server

As `SQL DMO` is deprecated now, I need to modify the below line in a `javascript` file to create `SQL SMO` automation object in `Javascript` using ActiveXObject :

```
var sql;
sql = new ActiveXObject("SQLDMO.SQLServer");
```

The above snippet is throwing `Automation server can't create object`.

The client system where this is running has SQL server 2014. I tried the below but the got the same error :

```
var sql;
sql = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server");
```

I also checked whether my system has `SQL SMO` installed or not in PowerShell :

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
```

I got the location of Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll as output:
  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

Please help me in creating the automation object using `SQL SMO`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have to use RegAsm to expose the .Net interface to COM.

http://www.progtown.com/topic336324-to-createnet-object-from-simple-jscript.html

Comment: Sorry to say that, I saw this link earlier also, but not sure what exactly needs to done here.

Comment: I registered Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll manually using RegAsm.exe and check again. Got the same error again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451812/how-to-do-regasm-so-that-it-cover-32-bit-and-64-bit . Sorry, but it's just going to require step by step troubleshooting. You're doing something non standard so there's not a well defined path documented anywhere online that I'm seeing.

Comment: When you say non-standard, is there any other way of doing it wih Javascript. I know it can be done via Powershell. But i dont want to change my whole script for this. Please suggest if there are other ways.

Comment: Doing it in JavaScript that requires an ActiveX interface to COM is non-standard and legacy. Powershell would be the standard way.