# 0x800a01ad - Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: c#, vbscript, com, interop

I've created Class library project with next code and settings:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyDll
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string[] SomeFunc(string path)
        {
            return new[] {"1","7","9"};
        }
    }
}
```

Also checked

> 'Make Assembly COM-Visible' in Properties/Application/Assembly information

and

> 'Register for COM interop' in Properties/Build

In my VBscript I am getting exception

> "0x800a01ad - Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component
>   can't create object: 'MyDll.TestClass'"

when trying to create object from dll:

```vb
Dim result
Dim myObj
Set myObj = CreateObject("MyDll.TestClass")
Set result= myObj.SomeFunc("a")
```

Comment: Have you [registered the actually DLL using `regsvr32.exe`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) *(the advice applies to both server-side and client-side VBScript)*?

Comment: 'Register for COM interop' in Properties/Build means registration dll by regasm.exe

Comment: for COM we need to use regasm.exe. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79314/How-to-call-a-NET-DLL-from-a-VBScript

Comment: But which registry is it being registered in? If `regasm.exe` is doing the job of `regsvr32.exe` or even calling it itself, which one is getting called? *(see that link for breakdown of 32-bit and 64-bit registry locations and how using the wrong `regsvr32.exe` can affect where it ends up)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using `regasm.exe` to add the Class into the registry but where in the registry?

Problem is we have the complication of dealing with both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, so couple of things spring to mind.

How are you running the script

```vb
Dim result
Dim myObj
Set myObj = CreateObject("MyDll.TestClass")
Set result= myObj.SomeFunc("a")
```

If you are using the default `wscript.exe` Windows Scripting Host to run the script then it will default to OS architecture which in most modern installations will be 64-bit OS.

If `regasm.exe` isn't registering the Class with the 64-bit registry then `CreateObject` will never find the prog id `MyDll.TestClass`.

Check through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) and see if you can see the Class in the registry, it details the various locations to check for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

---

#### Useful Links

- [@cynic answer to How to do RegAsm so that it cover 32-bit and 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452329/692942)